# Error accessing field by reflection for persistent property - one-to-one bidirectional

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

Hi I just learn to self code and currently am facing a 'small' issue. I am creating a one-to-one bidirectional mapping table linked by field "personId". I am mapping different fields other than the primary key to understand association mapping better.

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bGt0.png)

Employee entity (owning table)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
  private UUID id;
  
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
  private UUID personId;

  private String name;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Address address;

}
```

Address entity (referenced table)

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
  private UUID id;
  private String streetName;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName =  "personId",name = "person_id")
  private Employee employee;
}
```

Employee repository - I added Query Creation to find employee by name

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,UUID> {
  
  List<Employee> findByName(String name);
}
```

Address Repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address,UUID> {
      
    }
```

Employee service class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

  @Autowired
  private final EmployeeRepository empRepo;

  // GET BY NAME USING QUERY CREATION
  public List<Employee> getEmpByName(String name) {
    return empRepo.findByName(name);
  }

 // GET BY ID USING JPA
public Employee getEmpById(UUID id) {
    return empRepo.findById(id).get();
  }
}
```

Employee controller class:

```
@Data                
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/get-by-name/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getEmpByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeService.getEmpByName(name), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }

    @GetMapping("/get-by-id/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmpById(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeService.getEmpById(id), HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }
  }
```

And finally.. a test case (to add data)

```
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
  
  @Autowired
  private AddressRepository addressRepo;

  @Test
  @Order(1)
  public void addEmployeeWithoutAddress() {

     Employee e1 = Employee.builder().name("adam").build();
     Employee e2 = Employee.builder().name("bob").build();
     Employee e3 = Employee.builder().name("cat").build();
    employeeRepository.saveAll(List.of(e1, e2,e3));

  }
```

On start, I run the test case and checked my database and 3 values are added:

```
id                                  |name|person_id|
------------------------------------+----+---------+
d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61|adam|         |
451b7ef0-24cb-4637-8b93-5e486eae7644|bob |         |
64a14093-9740-4e9b-90c8-e574dbb60637|cat |         |
```

So far it was good. but, when I hit both requests I created, I got error:

/employee/get-by-name/adam

```
"message": "Error accessing field [private java.util.UUID com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee.personId] by reflection for persistent property [com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee#personId] : d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.util.UUID com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee.personId] by reflection for persistent property [com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee#personId] : d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61",
    "path": "/employee/get-by-name/adam"
```

/employee/get-by-id/d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61

```
   "message": "Error accessing field [private java.util.UUID com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee.personId] by reflection for persistent property [com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee#personId] : d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.util.UUID com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee.personId] by reflection for persistent property [com.shah.sharedprimarykeytable.entity.Employee#personId] : d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61",
    "path": "/employee/get-by-id/d606ebe2-2863-4de0-9fdd-c75f7faffe61"
```

This is the hibernate statement in my console on run time (FYI):

```
Hibernate: create table address (id uuid not null, street_name varchar(255), person_id uuid not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table employee (id uuid not null, name varchar(255), person_id uuid, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table address add constraint UK_5k57pkctki2o1wpmk2880r74j unique (person_id)
Hibernate: alter table employee add constraint UK_6rpeoojvw6pbporri8w66n164 unique (person_id)
Hibernate: alter table address add constraint FK59xm17jgujh9tgup907q101a3 foreign key (person_id) references employee (person_id)
```

I believe this is the simplest example on one-to-one bidirectional mapping table for me to understand. Everything was going good and I believe the mapping was done right. I checked for similar issue here but none seem to work for me. I have been trying for 3 days but can't seem to get it right but having no choice but to seek help out there. Hope I can find answers here.

UPDATE:

I saw one comment in other related question that Hibernate doesn't like bidirectional associations based on non-PK columns? Well I tried to use unidirectional, I removed this part in Employee entity:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Address address;
```

And some how it works. Any other workout for this?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266196/8382028

Comment: @ViaTech saw this post before.. not much of help..

Comment: Hi , Do you found answer for this question, I am also facing same issue

Comment: @santoshgore yes i did